# Check RadioGroup checked or not and get value to static int

Tags: android, static, int, radio-group

---

1. GOAL 1: When click the button, if there isn't any radiobutton checked, it will warning user by Toast; if a radiobutton checked, it will take user to new activity (or do smt up on you).

First

```
public class hanh1_2 extends Activity{

public static int ButID;
@Override
```

Second, set the button action:

```
final Button ok2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok2);
    ok2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Set int of ButID = checkedradiobuttonID
                            //If ButID = -1 --> there isn't bt checked
            int ButID = tieng.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            if (ButID == -1){
                Toast.makeText(hanh1_2.this, "Check a butt pls", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(hanh1_2.this,hanh1_3.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            }
        }
    });
```

Meaningless to advanced, but may helpful for some newbie like me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Have a look at the [Form stuff tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#RadioButtons) on the Android dev site. You can supply an OnClickListener to all RadioButtons and keep track of the one selected (if any).

   ```
   private OnClickListener radio_listener = new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // Perform action on clicks
           RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;
           Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, rb.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   };
   ```

   Alternatively, you can potentially use the RadioGroup's [`getCheckedRadioButtonId()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#getCheckedRadioButtonId%28%29) method.
2. As illustrated in one of the other answers: pass the int value as an extra to the Intent you use to launch your second Activity:

   ```
   // In first activity
   Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
   i.putInt("selected_index", selectedIndex);
   startActivity(i);

   // In second activity
   int selectedIndex = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("selected_index");
   ```

Comment: Thanks, the part 2 really help me. But the part 1, my goal is: When the user click ok2, if there is a radiobutton check, i will take him to next activity, else, i will toast.makeText warning him to check one.

Comment: I realise that, but you should not have any problems implementing that small piece of logic based on the information I gave. As a matter of fact, you already have 99% there. Just initialize `index1` to `1`: `index1 = -1;` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Take all your `RadioButton` and `RadioGroup` to class level.
initialize them inside `onCreate()`

now inside `onClick()` get id of checked `RadioButton` and compare like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {    

        int checked =   tieng.getCheckedRadioButtonId(); // tieng is your RadioGroup

        switch(checked)
        {
        case R.id.tieng1:
        Toast.makeText(hanh1_2.this, "First is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
        case R.id.tieng1:
        Toast.makeText(hanh1_2.this, "Second is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
        case R.id.tieng1:
        Toast.makeText(hanh1_2.this, "Third is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
        default:
        Toast.makeText(hanh1_2.this, "pleas check any button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

put extra along with intent :

```
else {
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(hanh1_2.this,hanh1_3.class);
        intent2.putInt(Index1, index1);
        startActivity(intent2);
        }
```

now inside second activity onCreate() read this extra :

```
{
int Index1 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Index1");

//do stuff here
```

}

Comment: Sorry but MH's answer below solve 2 of my problems so i accept it. I will vote for your answer when i have enough reputation point! Thank you!